# When should use 3NF design in data warehouse field

Tags: database, data-warehouse

I have one confusion about 3NF design and dimensional design in data warehouse field.

I don't want to cause a quarrel between Inmon and Kimball's idea, but as dimensional design causes less time for query and is easy to understand, I don't know when normalized design should be used, could someone give me a detail example for using normalized design better than denormalized one?

In my understanding, data warehouse is built for query, so it should order more read than write, more query than insert, I'd like to know when we should use normalized model, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I you are creating a data-warehouse you should have denormalized schema. To optimise you selects, also this allows for better reporting using BI, Cubes, Star Schemas etc. Warehouses are mainly this is for reporting puposes so will need better performance for selects over inserts/updates. It needs to be able to store historic data over dimensions such as time.

You would normalize your data model and use 3NF when working with an Operational Database. Which has updates, inserts, deletes and selects. Where you do not want to have duplicate data stored as it would make data consistancy difficult to maintain.

Comment: thanks, however, I think Inmon's idea is built for data warehouse, I agree with you and that's why I confuse: Inmon's idea is for normalized design or maybe we should say snowflake, am I right?